# Customizing nodes of an Azure Synapse Workspace Spark Cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-synapse

When creating a `Spark` cluster within an `Azure Synapse workspace`, is there a means to install arbitrary files and directories onto it's `cluster nodes` and/or onto the node's `underlying distributed filesystem`?

By arbitrary files and directories, I literally mean arbitrary files and directories; not just extra `Python` libraries like demonstrated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-azure-portal-add-libraries).

`Databricks` smartly provided a means to do this on it's cluster nodes (described in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/init-scripts#cluster-scoped-init-script)). Now I'm trying to see if there's a means to do the same on an `Azure Synapse Workspace Spark Cluster`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, Azure Synapse Analytics don't support arbitrary binary installs or writing to Spark local storage.

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Comment: Indeed we are speaking with MSFT, but I'll post there, too. Thank you.